# Send an email using mailKit in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, mailkit

I am trying to find a basic step-by-step tutorial to send an email in ASP.NET using mailKit but every tutorial talks about ASP.NET Core.

Can anyone point me to right direction? What should I use to send emails in MVC 5 and link a step-by-step tutorial?

I do not want to use smtpClient class as it is obsolete now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/wattanar/e8cee974456fd80d9ce649d951f36608  Check this code; it is an example :) Might help

Answer (score 1):

The code to send email using MailKit is the same in both ASP.NET MVC 5 and ASP.NET Core.